# Java JComboBox takes in ArrayList but doesn't show items of ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, arraylist, jcombobox

I am trying to fill a combobox with records out of my database. In my controller I am using MVC and in my Model I have a method getAllRoutes() that puts all the names of the routes out of the database into an ArrayList. This method works as intended as I have added a System.out.println() in it that shows that the ArrayList is indeed being filled with database values.

In my Controller, I create a new ArrayList called "routes" and initialize it with the ArrayList I have put in the return of the getAllRoutes() method. This also works as I have added a System.out.println() and it prints.

In my View, I create a new JComboBox, a new ArrayList comboBoxValues and a new method setComboBoxValues() that just fills the ArrayList comboBoxValues. Back in the Controller I call the setComboBoxValues() method and fill it with "routes" ArrayList.

But for some reason, when I run the program the JComboBox stays empty (see picture below). What am I doing wrong?

My Model:

```
package main.java.models;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import main.java.controllers.MapController;
import main.resources.ConnectionManager;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MapModel {
    List<String> coordinateList = new ArrayList<String>(); //deze moet naar fillCoordinateListArray

    public List<String> fillCoordinateListArray(int selected){
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
            String query = "SELECT RouteLocationID, RouteLocations.RouteID, X, Y FROM RouteLocations WHERE RouteID = ?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            stmt.setInt(1, 1);
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (results.next()) {
                double X = results.getDouble(3);
                double Y = results.getDouble(4);
                coordinateList.add(X + "," + Y);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Er is een fout opgetreden.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return coordinateList;
    } //method end

    public String parseCoordinates(){
        String text = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<coordinateList.size(); i++) {
            text+="&markers=label:" + (i+1) + "%7C" + coordinateList.get(i) + "%7C";

        }
        return text;
    } //method end

    public ArrayList getAllRoutes(){
        ArrayList<String> routeArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        try (Connection connection = ConnectionManager.getConnection()) {
            String query = "SELECT RouteID, RouteName FROM route";
            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (results.next()) {
                String routeName = results.getString(2);
                routeArrayList.add(routeName);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Er is een fout opgetreden.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(routeArrayList);
        return routeArrayList;
    } //method end


} //class end
```

My Controller:

```
import main.app.view.MapView;
import main.java.models.MapModel;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MapController {
    private MapView view;
    private MapModel model;

    public MapController(MapView view, MapModel model) {
        this.view = view;

        MapController.ListenerOfActions listener = new MapController.ListenerOfActions();
        view.addListenerOfActions(listener);
        this.model = model;
        this.model.getAllRoutes();

        ArrayList<String> routes = model.getAllRoutes();
        this.view.getRouteComboBox().getSelectedItem();
        this.view.setComboBoxValues(routes);
        System.out.println(routes);

        this.updateMap(1);
        this.view.setVisible(true);
    } //constructor end

    private void updateMap(int routeID){
        model.fillCoordinateListArray(routeID);
        Image image = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
                        "&size=600x450" +
                        "&maptype=roadmap" +
                        this.model.parseCoordinates() +
                        //"San+Francisco,CA" + "%7C" +
                        //"&markers=label:1%7C40.702147,-74.015794" + "%7C" +

                        "&key=AIzaSyAbLM94WcbkB-cf_ubHXOHmCDSsNWEz7XE");
                image = ImageIO.read(url);
              //  System.out.print(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ongeldige URL");
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.view.setImage(image);
        this.view.repaint();
    } //method end

    class ListenerOfActions implements ActionListener {
        int selected = 0;
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            if(actionCommand.equals("OK")) {
                int selected = view.getRouteComboBox().getSelectedIndex() + 1;
                System.out.println(selected);
                System.out.println("hallo");

                updateMap(selected);
            }

        }

        public int getSelected(){
            return this.selected;
        }


    } //class end
} //class end
```

My View:

```
package main.app.view;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;


import main.java.models.MapModel;
import main.resources.ConnectionManager;

public class MapView extends JPanel {
    public Image image;
    private JLabel jlImage;
    private JLabel jlName;
    private static JButton jbOk;
    private ArrayList<String> comboBoxValues;
    private JComboBox routeComboBox = new JComboBox();
    //private JComboBox<ArrayList<>>;
    private ActionListener actionListener;

    public MapView(){
        super(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(900, 450);
        this.add(getRouteComboBox());
        jbOk = new JButton("OK");
        jbOk.setActionCommand("OK");
        jbOk.addActionListener(this.actionListener);
        add(jbOk);
       // comboBoxValues.toArray();
    } //constructor end

    public void setComboBoxValues(ArrayList<String> comboBoxValues) {
        this.comboBoxValues = comboBoxValues;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image){
        this.image = image;
    }


    public MapView getView(){
        jlImage = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(this.image));
        add(jlImage);
        return this;
    }

    public void addListenerOfActions(ActionListener listenForAction) {
        this.actionListener = listenForAction;
    }

    public JComboBox getRouteComboBox(){
        return routeComboBox;
    }

} //class end
```

Picture of empty JComboBox:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW31W.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my View, I create a new JComboBox, a new ArrayList comboBoxValues and a new method setComboBoxValues() that just fills the ArrayList comboBoxValues.

So you have an ArrayList with data.

How do expect that data to magically appear in the combo box? The answer is it won't.

You need to copy the data from the ArrayList to the combo box in your `setComboBoxValues(…)`method:

Something like:

```
for (String item: comboBoxValues)
{
    comboBox.addItem( item );
}
```

In fact you don't even need the ArrayList in your view class, because the data will be stored in the model of the combo box.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for the basics.